# Android SlidingMenu implementation error

Tags: android, slidingmenu

My app has a minimum SDK value of 8 but it seems SlidingMenu requires 11 – is there a work around for this so it will work on minimum SDK version 8?

And when I increase to SDK#11 the app crashes with the following message:

FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat
E/AndroidRuntime(884): at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.initCustomViewAbove(CustomViewAbove.java:167)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think [Simple Side Drawer](https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer) works for Api 8. The exception you are seeing is probably because you are not including `android-support-v4` library in your project.

Comment: @vikram: thanks for your response. Can you tell me how to include android-support-v4?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at this guide: [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: @vikram: I have included android-support-v4 but it hasn't worked

Comment: Right click on your project in package explorer > choose properties > go to java build path > click on Libraries tab > expand Android Private Libraries > Do you see `android-support-v4.jar` in the list?

Comment: @vikram: No! There is no android-support-v4.jar. Only Access Rules & Native library location. I would appreciate your continued assistance

Comment: Let's talk here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35507/discussion-between-vikram-and-sisko)